# All-in-one IM messenger

Tags: windows-7

Im looking for a messenger that connects to multiple networks at the same time

It has to have these networks:

- Facebook
- Windows live
- Hyves (dutch)
- Twitter (well, preferrably just updates, but is optional)

Any tips on some good clients?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) can do all of those, but I don't think it does Twitter updates.

Comment: facebooks works if you set it up as jabber. https://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php

Comment: You can also use [this](http://code.google.com/p/pidgin-facebookchat/wiki/Downloads?tm=2) plugin to connect to Facebook with Pidgin.

Comment: Tried them both out, they're nice but ended up with Trillian! seems nicest so far :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windows, I suggest you [Digsby](http://www.digsby.com/) that integrates a lot of IM system and e-mail provider. It's a good software.

Comment: Digsby will be available for Linux soon.

Comment: I'm waiting for that :)

Comment: Digsby now has integrated ads, though. I've stopped using it for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

[miranda](http://www.miranda-im.org/) is a very simple, light multiplatform client that uses a native windows interface - its very small, lightweight, and supports all the usual suspects - MSN, Jabber, Yahoo etc.