# Suggest a good IM client which supports Gtalk, MSN and Facebook chat

Tags: windows-live-messenger, facebook, google-talk, rhel-6

Suggest a good IM client which supports Gtalk, MSN and Facebook chat.

PS: I am using RHEL 6, I have [kopete](http://kopete.kde.org/) but it doesn't support facebook.

Comment: possible duplicate of [All-in-one IM messenger](http://superuser.com/questions/303779/all-in-one-im-messenger)

Comment: in addition to that, you can connect to facebook over jabber using the instructions [here](https://www.facebook.com/sitetour/chat.php)  as per my comments in that question

Comment: This Q relates to Linux (RHEL6), but the 'possible dupe' question relates to Windows, so not really a dupe - mind you, the Q is qoing to elicit subjective answers for a 'good' IM client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found by Journeyman Geek:

[InstantBird](http://instantbird.com/) is a free IM client that claims support for the following IM protocols:

- AIM
- **MSN**
- Yahoo
- **Google Talk**
- Twitter
- **Facebook**
- XMPP
- IRC
- ICQ

I have bolded the three that you specified.  You can find versions for Windows MacOS and Linux, of which RHEL is a derivative so I would expect it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Use [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/).

It supports:

- AIM
- Bonjour
- Gadu-Gadu
- Google Talk
- Groupwise
- ICQ
- IRC
- MSN
- MXit
- MySpaceIM
- SILC
- SIMPLE
- Sametime
- XMPP
- Yahoo!
- Zephyr

You mentioned Facebook chat, [follow this guide](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2010/02/12/how-to-use-facebook-chat-with-pidgin/) to get that configured to work properly in pidgin.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: InstantBird looks like a very similar client. I should point out that the facebook protocol is XMPP, so using Facebook chat on Pidgin is just a matter of adding account info in the right place. Pidgin, formerly known as gaim, also has been around a very long time and been well maintained. There is a fairly decent plugin architecture for it, including otr support, amongst many other things. Plus, indeed it runs on Windows and Linux.. I'm not sure if they have an OSX build, though you could run it via macports or just get Adium for osx.

Comment: Pidgin is quite frustrating to use. Almost no features, ugly, annoying notifications... on in all: amateur's job!

Comment: @Lucas-luky-N. No, you are mistaken my friend.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use [Miranda IM](http://www.miranda-im.org/)

It's made for Windows (exclusively. It uses Windows 7 Aero features for example), so it doesn't have the strange quirks the ported software often has. Also it's open source.

All your protocols are supported. Here is a list:

AIM, Battle.NET, C6, Facebook, Gadu-Gadu, Google Mail Notifier, Google Talk, IAX (InterAsterisk), IChat, ICQ, IRC, Jabber, QQ, MSN, MySpace, Omegle, SIP, Skype, Sametime, Tlen, Twitter, VKontakte, VyChat, XFire, Yahoo

Some protocols have more than one implementation.

Additionally the whole UI is pluggable too. The whole thing is completely pluggable.

There's also special things that also plug in:

HTTPServer, MDynDns, Ping, RSS News, Weather, Radio streaming, Screenshot sending, WebCam, Whiteboard (Only works to Miranda), Logitech G15 plugin, PHP and Python scripting, games (Tic Tac Toe, Chess4Net, Battleships, ...)

Theres also plugins which encrypt your chats like OTR-Messaging (Off The Record). This plugin is also compatible with Trillians OTR for example.

Answer (score 0):

[imo.im](https://imo.im) is a free web-based instant messaging service. It is ad-free, https-secured and supports the following networks:

- **MSN**
- Skype
- Yahoo!
- **Google Talk**
- **Facebook**
- AIM / ICQ
- Jabber
- VKontakte
- MySpace
- Hyves

Answer (score 0):

I have used Meebo with some success. It's a web client that works with just about all the IM systems out there, and it has mobile versions as well.

The Meebo staff seem to be pretty good at including new IM systems and updating the system frequently.

However, they do have a small banner on the bottom of the window that kinda reminds me of Myspace, advertising bands and the like. It is easily minimized and very unobtrusive.

Meebo is also used to provide social network interaction on websites. You'll see their bottom bar on several news sites and blogs. In my experience, it tends to be the most popular of these bars, providing site interaction with all major social networks. If you're logged into Meebo and you come across one of these sites, you get more tools for sharing the site with your IM friends.